# Countdown date time References time from pc not server , how to change it's

Tags: php, jquery, date, time, countdown

Countdown date time References time from pc not server , how to change it's

i use this code for countdown date time, when i change date time in my pc

countdown date time will change too (date time References time from pc) 
how to change date time References from server

http://jsfiddle.net/H7Zaj/2/

```
$('.countdown').downCount({
            date: '08/05/2015 00:23:50',
            offset: +7
        }, function () {

$('.menu').fadeIn("slow");
$('.menu2').fadeOut("slow");

        });
```

Answer (score 0):

First you have find server time zone then your pc time zone. Calculate difference between server and your pc time zone. You have to set  -/+ offset for getting correct time zone.

Comment: but if user change pc time ?]

Comment: $timezone = date_default_timezone_get();
$dtz = new DateTimeZone($timezone);
$time_in_Europe = new DateTime('now', $dtz);
$EuropeTimeZone= $dtz->getOffset( $time_in_Europe );echo "<br/>";
$offset = $dtz->getOffset( $time_in_Europe ) / 3600;
$timeZoneGMT= ($offset < 0 ? $offset : "+".$offset);  
echo $timeZoneGMT; same way u also find server time zone.then calculate different .